# SAPUI5 oData PUT operation requires GET ENTITY implementation

Tags: odata, sapui5, crud, put

I implemented the update operation for an oData service. When I tried to call it via my SAPUI5 application, I got the following error message:

> 'XXX_GET_ENTITY' not implemented in data provider class

That's true - I did not yet implement the GET ENTITY method. 
However, can someone tell me why I need this one for an update?

The JS coding for the service request is created this way:

```
oDataModel.update("/EntitySetName(<key>)", oPayload, {
   success: function(oData) {
      ...
   },
   error: function(oError) {
      ...
   }
});
```

I appreciate every hint / explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default update method for the ODataModel is a patch/merge, see the documentation from the ODataModel class:

> Trigger a PUT/MERGE request to the OData service that was specified in
>   the model constructor.
>
> The update method used is defined by the global defaultUpdateMethod
>   parameter which is sap.ui.model.odata.UpdateMethod.Merge by default. [...]

The default implementation of the PATCH_ENTITY method calls the READ_ENTITY first and then merges the incoming data with the retrieved data to allow for partial updates. From the comments in this method:

```
*-a patch request is a partial update of an entity. All provided components are patched.
*-The default implementation of patch_entity performs a read before update [...]
```

To do a PUT request, set the updateMethod property to sap.ui.model.odata.UpdateMethod.Put.